# Combining data frames horizontally in R with names

Tags: r, list, merge

I have a set of 12 data frames (DF1, DF2,... DF12) with a similar format like this:

```
> DF1
# A tibble: 12 x 6
   month     mean  max   min   sd        n
   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
 1 January   1.22    x     x     x      x
 2 February  2.23    x     x     x      x
 3 March     4.86    x     x     x      x
 4 April     7.82    x     x     x      x
 5 May        -      -     -     -      x
 6 June       -      -     -     -      x
 7 July       -      -     -     -      x
 8 August     -      -     -     -      x
 9 September  -      -     -     -      x
10 October    -      -     -     -      x
11 November   -      -     -     -      x
12 December   -      -     -     -      x
```

The data frames are always similar (12X6) and the column names too (month, mean, max, min, sd, n). How can I do to combine the 12 data frames horizontally to obtain something like this (with the names of the DF above) :

```
                   "name of the DF1"                           "name of the DF2"                 "name of the DF3"             ....
   month     mean.x max.x min.x sd.x n.x   mean.y       max.y       min.y sd.y n.y
1  January      -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
2  February     -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
3  March        -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
4  April        -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
5  May          -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
6  June         -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
7  July         -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
8  August       -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
9  September    -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
10 October      -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
11 November     -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
12 December     -     -     -    -   -    -           -           -    -   -
```

I have a list containing my 12 data frames :

```
var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^Final_analysis")
DF<- mget(var_names)
```

Comment: Hello :) I am wondering why you want to acheive this nice human-readible display in R. To perform further analysis, I think this is not recommended (see https://r4ds.had.co.nz/tidy-data.html). If you want a "nice looking document" I suggest you have a look to Rmarkdown and `kable()` like functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::bind_cols(DF)` can do the trick.

Comment: Exactly, it works! In this analysis the 12 DF have values everywhere. Now, I would like to obtain something quite automatic and in another analysis with another set of 12 DF, the last DF is empty (no data available in this table, it is normal in this analysis). And in this case, R returns me "Error: Argument 12 must be length 12, not 0". Is it possible to add something such as "do like the other DF, even if you're empty" ?

Comment: It returns the error because the last df is empty. Maybe you can artificially create a df with the same size (12x5), and fill it with NAs.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have multi-index data frames in R. So there is no way to have the DF names above the colnames. To bind them together anyway, try the following:

```
var_names <- ls(pattern = "^Final_analysis")
do.call(cbind, mget(var_names))
```

Comment: But then I just obtain a list                                                                                                   ` > var_names <- ls(envir = globalenv(), pattern = "^Final_analysis")
> DF<- mget(var_names)
> a <- do.call(cbind, list(DF))
> a
                            [,1]  
DF1    List,6
DF2    List,6
DF3    List,6
DF4    List,6
DF5    List,6
DF6    List,6
... `

Comment: You do not need to use `list() `in that case. Just do this: ```do.call(cbind, mget(var_names))```

Answer (score 1):

As @Eyayaw mentioned, it's not possible to have the DF names appear above the column names.

However, we can get around this by pasting the DF names to the column names before combining everything with `dplyr::bind_cols()` as suggested by @grouah

One approach to do this using the [*dplyr*](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) and [*purrr*](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/) packages:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

# Create NAMED list of dataframes
df_list <- list("mtcars1" = mtcars, "mtcars2" = mtcars, "mtcars3" = mtcars)
# Add name of df to colnames
df_list <- imap(df_list, function(df, name) {
    colnames(df) <- paste(colnames(df), name, sep = "_")
    df
})
# Check result
map(df_list, colnames)
#> $mtcars1
#>  [1] "mpg_mtcars1"  "cyl_mtcars1"  "disp_mtcars1" "hp_mtcars1"   "drat_mtcars1"
#>  [6] "wt_mtcars1"   "qsec_mtcars1" "vs_mtcars1"   "am_mtcars1"   "gear_mtcars1"
#> [11] "carb_mtcars1"
#> 
#> $mtcars2
#>  [1] "mpg_mtcars2"  "cyl_mtcars2"  "disp_mtcars2" "hp_mtcars2"   "drat_mtcars2"
#>  [6] "wt_mtcars2"   "qsec_mtcars2" "vs_mtcars2"   "am_mtcars2"   "gear_mtcars2"
#> [11] "carb_mtcars2"
#> 
#> $mtcars3
#>  [1] "mpg_mtcars3"  "cyl_mtcars3"  "disp_mtcars3" "hp_mtcars3"   "drat_mtcars3"
#>  [6] "wt_mtcars3"   "qsec_mtcars3" "vs_mtcars3"   "am_mtcars3"   "gear_mtcars3"
#> [11] "carb_mtcars3"

# bind_cols() everything together
combined <- bind_cols(df_list)
colnames(combined)
#>  [1] "mpg_mtcars1"  "cyl_mtcars1"  "disp_mtcars1" "hp_mtcars1"   "drat_mtcars1"
#>  [6] "wt_mtcars1"   "qsec_mtcars1" "vs_mtcars1"   "am_mtcars1"   "gear_mtcars1"
#> [11] "carb_mtcars1" "mpg_mtcars2"  "cyl_mtcars2"  "disp_mtcars2" "hp_mtcars2"  
#> [16] "drat_mtcars2" "wt_mtcars2"   "qsec_mtcars2" "vs_mtcars2"   "am_mtcars2"  
#> [21] "gear_mtcars2" "carb_mtcars2" "mpg_mtcars3"  "cyl_mtcars3"  "disp_mtcars3"
#> [26] "hp_mtcars3"   "drat_mtcars3" "wt_mtcars3"   "qsec_mtcars3" "vs_mtcars3"  
#> [31] "am_mtcars3"   "gear_mtcars3" "carb_mtcars3"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

As an example I just used the `mtcars` data 3 times in the DF list, but this should work for any **named** list of data frames which have the **same number of rows** (number of columns can be different).